# Django design patterns for overriding models

Tags: django, inversion-of-control

I'm working on an e-commerce framework for Django. The chief design goal is to provide the bare minimum functionality in terms of models and view, instead allowing the users of the library to extend or replace the components with their own.

The reasoning for this is that trying to develop a one-size-fits-all solution to e-commerce leads to overcomplicated code which is often far from optimal.

One approach to tackling this seems to be using inversion-of-control, either through Django's settings file or import hacks, but I've come up against a bit of a problem due to how Django registers its models.

The e-commerce framework provides a bunch of abstract models, as well as concrete versions in {app_label}/models.py. Views make use of Django's `get_model(app_label,model)` function to return the model class without having to hard-code the reference.

This approach has some problems:

1. Users have to mimic the structure of the framework's apps, ie the app_label and effectively replace our version of the app with their own
2. Because of the way the admin site works by looking for admin.py in each installed app, they have to mimic or explicitly import the framework's admin classes in order to use them. But by importing them, the register method gets called so they have to be unregistered if a user wants to customise them.
3. The user has to be extremely careful about how they import concrete models from the core framework. This is because Django's base model metaclass automatically registers a model with the app cache as soon as the class definition is read (ie upon `__new__`), and the first model registered with a specific label is the one you're stuck with. So you have to define all your override models BEFORE you import any of the core models. This means you end up with messy situations of having a bunch of imports at the bottom of your modules rather than the top.

My thinking is to go further down the inversion-of-control rabbit hole:

1. All references to core components (models, views, admin, etc) replaced with calls to an IoC container
2. For all the core (e-commerce framework) models, replace the use of Django's base model metaclass with one that doesn't automatically register the models, then have the container explicitly register them on startup.

**My question:**

Is there a better way to solve this problem? The goal is to make it easy to customise the framework and override functionality without having to learn lots of annoying tricks. The key seems to be with models and the admin site.

I appreciate that using an IoC container isn't a common pattern in the Django world, so I want to avoid it if possible, but it is seeming like the right solution.

Comment: sounds interesting! have you seen [Satchless](http://satchless.com/)? they are going in a similar direction I think, also trying to solve the issue of making all the framework models abstract. [Mamona](https://github.com/emesik/mamona) payments backend uses an 'AbstractMixin' hack that might be useful

Comment: I have seen Satchless. I'm actually working with the creators of it on  a project that uses the platform I'm working on. Lots of great cross-pollination of ideas going on. I'll take a look at Mamona, it looks interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the code from other projects with a similar approach?
Not sure if this way covers your needs, but imo the code of [django-shop](https://github.com/divio/django-shop) is worth to look at.

This framework provides the basic logic, allowing you to provide custom logic where needed.

#### customize via models

eg see the [productmodel.py](https://github.com/divio/django-shop/blob/master/shop/models/productmodel.py)

```
#==============================================================================
# Extensibility
#==============================================================================
PRODUCT_MODEL = getattr(settings, 'SHOP_PRODUCT_MODEL',
    'shop.models.defaults.product.Product')
Product = load_class(PRODUCT_MODEL, 'SHOP_PRODUCT_MODEL')
```

#### customize via logic/urls

eg see the shop's [simplevariation-plugin](https://github.com/chrisglass/django-shop-simplevariations)
It extends the cart-logic, so it hooks in via urlpattern:

```
(r'^shop/cart/', include(simplevariations_urls)),
(r'^shop/', include(shop_urls)),
```

and extends the views:
    ...

```
from shop.views.cart import CartDetails

class SimplevariationCartDetails(CartDetails):
    """Cart view that answers GET and POSTS request."""
...
```

The framework provides several points to hook-in, the simplevariation-plugin mentionned above additionally provides a cart-modifier:

```
SHOP_CART_MODIFIERS = [
    ...
    'shop_simplevariations.cart_modifier.ProductOptionsModifier',
    ...
]
```

I worry that this explanation is not very understandable, it is difficult to briefly summarize this concept. But take a look at the django-shop project and some of its extensions: [ecosystem](https://www.django-shop.org/en/ecosystem/)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there can only be one default model per module. ie the product model exists by itself in product.py.

As soon as you have more than one model in the module, they'll all get registered the second you try and use any one of them.